# Windows Phone 8.1 MediaCapture CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync memory leak

Tags: camera, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, universal

I am building a universal app for timelapse that captures a sequence of photos at a specified interval. In my timer tick event, I am capturing an image and saving it to a storage file like this:

```
StorageFile file = await appFolder.CreateFileAsync(IMAGE_FILE_ROOT, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
await MediaCaptureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, file);
ImageFilePaths.Add(file.Path);
file = null;
```

After successfully capturing around 30 images at the highest resolution (140 on low res) on my phone, I get an Out of Memory exception on the CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync method.

I tried just taking the photo to an InMemoryRandomAccessStream so that I could elliminate the StorageFile API for the leak, and it still leaks.

I profiled the memory utilization with the WinPhone Power Tools and it is a constant rise while photos are being taken.

Is there anything I can do to work around this?

Update:

Here is test code that demonstrates the leak:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await MediaCaptureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageProperties, memoryStream);
    }

    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you share a little bit more code- it might be helpful

Comment: So I am taking photos with the MediaCapture API in my WinPhone app every 2 seconds (to later create a timelapse video with).  The code works fine (takes the photos and saves them), but after about 30 photos, the app runs out of memory.

Comment: I ran Windows Phone Power Tools and did a memory profile of the app, and it is steadily consuming more and more memory until it crashes.  FYI, there is plenty of free storage on the phone for the pics.

Comment: To attempt to isolate the leak, I profiled the following test code, and got the same problem:  for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
{
 using (IRandomAccessStream memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
 {
  await MediaCaptureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageProperties, memoryStream);
 }

 await Task.Delay(1000);
}

Comment: Also, I tried to dispose the MediaCaptureManager and re-initialize it after taking a photo, but the leak persists.

Comment: Is the loop inside the method?

Comment: So the loop is sample code living in a command that is executed from a button click.  I do the MediaCaptureManager initialization elsewhere in the ViewModel.

Comment: Here is a sample solution that you can run to see the problem: http://1drv.ms/1tKxEw5

Comment: Update:  I do not see the leak appear when I run my sample project in the emulator, only on my Lumia devices.

Comment: Update:  Leak does not occur on HTC 8X.  It must be a Nokia problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to work around the issue!

Apparently the memory leak has something to do with the audio driver.  If you initialize the MediaCaptureManager like this, the leak disappears.

```
var mediaSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
 {
  PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Auto,
  StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
  AudioDeviceId = string.Empty
 };
```